# How do I get this question about adapting buttons for iPhone sizes re-opened after improving it?

Tags: support, specific-question, reopen-closed

I understood what the OP was asking on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38569620/how-to-adapt-the-position-of-a-uibutton-to-a-background-image-for-all-iphone-siz), and I answered the question. Still, the question was put on hold, then closed.

Now, I have also edited the question and title to improve it, and I think it should be pretty clear what the OP was asking.

I understood from other posts in this meta that editing the question would get it reviewed, and hopefully re-opened. However, this doesn't seem to be happening.

What do I need to do to get his question re-opened? (Or, can the OP mark my answer, even on a closed question?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, editing is the most important thing. A fast edit can prevent the question from being closed entirely; an edit soon after closing can encourage reviewers to reopen [when the question goes through review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/13156102).

But if none of that helps (in this case, it appears to have taken several edits to get the question into shape), posting here is a good option. If nothing else, folks can offer further guidance as to what the question needs, or if salvage is possible.

I did some minor cleanup and reopened.